# Nikon Coolpix 885 not saving to new 8gb memory card

Tags: nikon, memory-card

I have a Nikon Coolpix 885 and an 8gb memory card. I divided the card into two partitions (the primary is 2 Gb formatted fat 16). Everything seems to work well but when I shoot I only get black pictures and, if I to go to the Play menu it says "File contains no image data." Is there a way to make this new card work?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you think "everything seems to work well" when you're not getting any images on the card, that seems the opposite. Have you tried formatting the card in the camera? Without a partition that doesn't seem to make any sense?

Comment: JoanneC: The camera needs to be able to deal with the MBR etc. and over 2gb the partition table format changes to allow for larger volumes, it's unlikely the 13 year old 885 will be able to handle it at all, but if it can then formatting in camera will do it.

Comment: Thanks Joanne for you reply, James got the point, unfortunately when I try to format the card in camera I get the out of memory message as the camera try to format the whole 8gb card 16 fat.

Comment: @JamesSnell - Good point, I didn't look up the camera. I tend to agree with your answer then, the camera simply won't handle it.

Answer (score 4):

The Coolpix 885 is a very old camera and it simply cannot address a card that big.

The file system is only a guide to how data is organised and has nothing to do with how write operations are handled at the interface/card level.  The camera needs to be able to write to any part of the card even if it is never going to be used by a partition/file.

The biggest card you'll be able to use is 2gb as there is a change in the partitioning system / MBR representation for larger cards.

---

*I was using 2gb CF cards in a Coolpix 880 which predates the 885 and the 4300 which supersedes it, if you stick to that you should be fine.*

Comment: thanks James, I just  hoped there was a trick to make it work, as i don't have any other device to use this memory card with. according to this post (http://www.techsupportforum.com/222-newly-formatted-4gb-compact-flash-card-out-of-memory-digital-camera/) that trick seems to work with the 4300. anyway, i'll buy a new 2gb card. thanks again

Comment: I didn't get it to work on my 4300, maybe it's a firmware thing?

Comment: may be, anyway just to try everything i'm going to upgrade the firmware; i don't think it will change anything but i decided to give it a chance, who knows....